# ¿Existe una pregunta canónica para StringIndexOutOfBoundsException en Java?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, preguntas

Estaba respondiendo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607064/tengo-problemas-con-un-error-el-cual-no-entiendo-por-que-aparece) relacionada con la excepción `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` pero pensaba marcarla como duplicada porque suponía que existiría una canónica al respecto como la de NullPointerException, pero no la he encontrado.

Me da la sensación de que en la mayoría de los casos es siempre el mismo problema, que el OP no está controlando bien los índices porque no acaba de asimilar que van de 0 a la longitud de la cadena menos uno y falla al escribir la condición de un bucle.

¿Existe dicha pregunta canónica?

Comment: Aparentemente no, no existe y me parecería una muy buena idea crear una dado que parece ser un error bastante común. Si te animas, avisa para que quede reflejado por aqui.

Comment: no te recomiendo crear algo generico para responder ese tipo de errores comunes, la comunidad lo ve mal y termina metiendote votos negativos de castigo.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Hombre, ya existen precedentes como el que he mencionado o el que aparece relacionado ahí a la derecha para NullReferenceException

Comment: como quieras ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tenemos respuestas para problemas comunes que se repiten siempre todo el tiempo... las null pointer son un claro ejemplo...

Comment: Que es una pregunta canónica ?????

Comment: @Yussef Una pregunta que sirva de respuesta estándar para un problema típico repetitivo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42977/5896 De forma que otras preguntas muy parecidas se marquen como duplicadas

Comment: @RubioRic Pero eso es a modo de acuerdo tácito  o hay un botón de "marcar como canónica" ???

Comment: @Yussef Pues no creo que exista tal botón. No tengo claro cómo se llega a ese acuerdo, por eso lo preguntaba por aquí

Comment: Ojalá alguien me pueda explicar el concepto y que se distingue con una pregunta "normal".

Comment: Y para ser sinceros a mi esa pregunta del `NullPointerException` me parece mal formulada y mal redactada (no así la respuesta)

Comment: @Yussef de ahi que la llamemos pregunta canonica... no nos importa la pregunta en si, o como esta redactada, o si no es perfecta. Nos importa que la respuesta sea lo mas completa posible y conteste siempre a las preguntas con el mismo problema, este como este escrita. No se marca a una respuesta asi, es un acuerdo.. Todos los null pointer exception de java o C# se mandan a su respectiva "canonica" que contesta siempre bien a todas, pq el problema es siempre el mismo...

Comment: No existe tal cosa como preguntas canónicas. Lo que hay son respuestas canónicas y pares de pregunta/respuesta canónica que tienen la intención de ser utilizadas como destino de duplicación de preguntas frecuentes. Encontrarás más información (en inglés) en meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/255257

Comment: @jachguate No sé a quien iba dirigido el comentario pero la respuesta que enlazas comienza con "a canonical question".  Lo cual contradice tu primera frase. El concepto lo conocíamos la mayoría, aunque está bien saber donde se "metadefine", gracias!

Comment: @Rubio mi respuesta no iba dirigida a nadie en particular. El concepto yo lo traigo desde que Joel Spolsky, uno de los fundadores de SO hablaba sobre el tema en su blog y creo que quizás la redacción de la respuesta que en lazo no es la más clara. Como yo lo entiendo, no puede haber una pregunta canónica sin que la respuesta sea canónica. Es decir, por muy bien planteada que esté la pregunta y aunque se haya hecho con ese fin, lo que la hace canónica es la respuesta, o en último caso es canónico el par pregunta/respuesta, pero no la pregunta sola.